# React having onClick work only once on a component

Tags: reactjs, onclick

Hello I am trying to build a forum site. I have simple categories and comments. I have a button that displays a text box to enter a comment on a category, but when I click the button it opens text boxes on every category. I just want one text box. Here is the code I have so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
state = { showing: true };

renderLists(categories) {
  const { showing } = this.state;

  if (categories == null) return <div />;
  return (
    <ul className="ul">
      {categories.map(category => {
        return (
          <li id={category._id} className="categories" key={category._id}>
            {category.name}

            <Posts categ={category._id} />
            <button
              className="label"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ showing: !showing })}
            >
              Add Comment
            </button>
            {showing ? (
              <div>
                <form method="post" action="/post/create-posts">
                  <input type="text" name="body" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="cat" value={category._id} />
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <main className="categories">
        {this.renderLists(this.state.category)}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just create another component, say Category, and hold the `showing` state there. This is more modular and more performant, you'll prevent re-rendering the whole list

Comment: you can also go this way: this.setState({showing:categoryID}) and only display when this.state.showing === category._id

Answer (score 0):

Since you are controlling render of the form with a single state value, ever form for every item renders the form when the state value changes.

You should set a unique value on state to show single form every time.

Saving currently active items id to state and checking if that item is active or not can be a simple solution. This also ensures to only single form to be active. If you need to enable multiple forms to be active, you can change below code to hold an array of ids and checking if the id exist in array or not. This implementation also requires you to remove the id from array on a second click to remove form for that item.

**Sample**

```
state = { showing: ''};

renderLists(categories) {
  const { showing } = this.state;

  if (categories == null) return <div />;
  return (
    <ul className="ul">
      {categories.map(category => {
        return (
          <li id={category._id} className="categories" key={category._id}>
            {category.name}

            <Posts categ={category._id} />
            <button
              className="label"
              {/* Save item's id to state */}
              onClick={() => this.setState({ showing: category._id })}
            >
              Add Comment
            </button>
            {/* check item's id */}
            {(showing === category._id) ? (
              <div>
                <form method="post" action="/post/create-posts">
                  <input type="text" name="body" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="cat" value={category._id} />
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dynamic state for each of your category. I have made it below. Initially it was not there in state. On clicking the button, it will update the state with new key(such as categoryName) as true. I have fixed it as toggle. If the required key is true then it will become false.

```
item.state = { showing: true };

renderLists(categories) {
  const { showing } = this.state;

  if (categories == null) return <div />;
  return (
    <ul className="ul">
      {categories.map(category => {
        let categoryName = category.name  // get the categoryName in variable

        return (
          <li id={category._id} className="categories" key={category._id}>
            {category.name}

            <Posts categ={category._id} />
            //You can also access the object values by using bracket ([]) notation. You can set the dynamic state with unique key, may be we use name as key here
            <button
              className="label"
              onClick={() => {(this.state[categoryName] != undefined) ? (this.state[categoryName] ? this.setState({ [categoryName]: false }) : this.setState({ [categoryName]: true })) : this.setState({ [categoryName]: true })} } 
            >
              Add Comment
            </button>
            {this.state[categoryName] ? (
              <div>
                <form method="post" action="/post/create-posts">
                  <input type="text" name="body" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="cat" value={category._id} />
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <main className="categories">
        {this.renderLists(this.state.category)}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```